# rdlc doesn't load fonts

Tags: reportviewer, report

I have a rdlc report which is created in server (IIS) and then delivered to client after converting it to PDF.
all things are ok when I run the site on my local IIS but when running the web site on the server(win2003) , my special fonts are not rendered correctly. I copied all the fonts I have in my local windows\fonts folder to the server font folder but nothing changed.
Did I missed something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

oh my god! restarting the server+disabling the anti-virus solved my problems. because of doing these two jobs at the same time , I don't know what the source of the problem  exactly was. but as described in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/donovans/archive/2007/07/20/reporting-services-pdf-renderer-faq.aspx I need to restart after installing new fonts! so strange but solved my problem after about 6 hours!